# if third letter is equal to

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell which contains any 4 letters, example akei, skiw. How do I ask

"if the 3rd letter is an i then equals True"

I was thinking something like

"=if(a1="??i?", True, False)"

But that dosen't Work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=MID(A1,3,1) = "i"
```

Should work, you don't need to use `IF`, the evaluation using the equals will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Answer (score 3):

The MID function let you to select a portion of the text, if you set the Position Start and the numbers of characters you want

```
=MID(A1,3,1) = "i"
```

so you just compare it to "i"

Answer (score 2):

You could use the wildcard approach if you use COUNTIF like this

`=COUNTIF(A1,"??i?")`

That will return 1 or 0 and effectively tests two things, that A1 contains 4 characters AND the third one is "i"

As with MID this isn't case-sensitive so 1 will be returned for both XXIX and zziz

Comment: also `=COUNTIF(A1,"??i*")` if A1 contains more than 4 letters word.

Answer (score 0):

So I came upon this question for a similar use: Expanding a numbering system for lab specimen with each digit distinguishing something different and the 3rd digit indicating a heating profile

The resulting function was used to expand these codes out for people that would not know my logic otherwise:

```
=IF(MID(B2,3,1) = "1", "Temp1°C for 1 hour", "Temp2°C for X hours")
```

Comment: The answer should, where possible, answer the question as posted, not a similar but distinct question. This would make it more obvious to the question asker how the solution fits his problem.